# facebook canvas app authentication single sign on does not work on safari 5

Tags: facebook, safari

I have been using single sign on authentication for my facebook canvas iframe app.
It works fine on IE, Firefox, Chrome(all latest). But doesn't work on Safari 5.

I know safari doesn't allow *cross-domain cookies*, and that's the reason it's not working. Facebook sets cookie for my app's domain that I can use as *single sign on* mechanism.

*If* I go to Safari's Preferences and set to allow cookies always and not only for sites I have visited, *the entire app works fine*. But, I don't expect every single safari user of my app to be doing that.

Has any one got this working? I tried using couple of other apps, and they seem to work but not sure if they use single sign on approach to authentication, which is actually recommended by facebook documentation. Do you think I should be using another approach that can fix it for me?

Info: I'm using ASP .NET MVC 2

Thanks

Comment: As lame as it sounds, our company simply tells our users to use a different browser.  I am the first one to admit that this is far from ideal.  Unfortunately, the work-arounds are complex and aggravating.  This was a popular post on the subject:  http://wcrawford.org/2007/08/29/revisited-facebook-safari-and-external-iframes-that-need-cookies/.  I've implemented something similar for a MySpace application, but it was a bit easier there as the session id is available in the canvas before the application even loads.

Comment: Even if we do authentication by some other mechanism and don't follow single sign on. Javascript SDK calls won't work going further, right?

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty well for me.. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=257432#p257432

Comment: Can't remember anymore but the issue was something like this. Safari doesn't cache 3rd party cookies so you have to make it seem like the cookies being redirected are from a trusted source. All you need to do is feed the URL of the application source to a parameter on the facebook API exposed function that parses the cookies of the 3rd party site as fb cookies, so safari is fooled into thinking the site  is a trusted site and allows you to render the page without refreshing continuously.

Comment: Alternate solution is to explain users to configure safari to store third party cookies.